# How to iterate values in Python

Tags: python

```
player_details=[{'name': u'Bryan Barker', 'pos': u'P', 'birthdate': datetime.date(1964, 6, 28), 'team_id': 14L, 'birthcity': u'Jacksonville Beach', 'id': 1107L, 'uno': u'4'}]
```

How to get team_id from above. I tried `player_details['team_id']`

Comment: Are you have a list of dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`player_details` is a list, you should first access the element of it.

```
player_details[0]['team_id']
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a list containing a dict (the outer square brackets indicate a list, which contains one item - the inner curly brackets signifying a dict with the contents indicated). You need to get the first item from the list, then access the data from the dict you get:

```
player_details[0]['team_id']
```

Of course, the list implies there might be multiple items, so you might want to iterate over the list and get each value in turn, depending on your use case.

```
for player in player_details:
    do_something(player['team_id'])
```